# How to get which row currently iterating for loop list using python

Tags: python

```
import xlrd
file_location = "/home/myuser/excel.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]

for r in data:
    print r[1]
```

i want to get which row in excel is iterating in the for loop, Can anybody help me regarding this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What does your code currently do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what _get which row in excel is iterating in the for loop_ means.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops

Comment: I need to handle the rows in xlsx based on iteration count. using r[1] inside for loop i am able to get 1st column value in 1st row. now i need after few iterations, how to get which row is currently iterating and if i want to get previous iteration values. how can get them in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`:

```
for i, r in enumerate(data):
    print 'current row is {}'.format(i)
    print r[1]
```

If you want to count from `1` just use `enumerate(data, 1)`.

Comment: thanks, if i want to get previous iteration values ex : if i want to get previous row value how can i get.

Comment: @Srikanth well You can subtract `1` but remember that there is no previous value for the first, so you'd have to figure out what you want in that case

Comment: i want previous value after first iteration, suppose if i want to get text in 2nd row column 1&2, i need to check 1st row columns 1&2 values in 2nd iteration. how to solve that. i have tried with subtraction but i did not get previous values.

Comment: @Srikanth Given that you seem to have a question there, why don't you write that in another question, include example of input and desired output, and you might get awesome answers?

Comment: I need to get row count and particular column values using python list iteration 
for every row in excel i need to get username and password.
i have used the below code.
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
     sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
     vendor = [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(1,sheet.nrows)]
           
     for i in vendor:
        user_name = i[1]
        password=i[2]
like this when first iteration is completed, i need to check previous username and password and need to compare with 2nd iteration values.